# Qt: mainwindow application

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qtgui

I would like to build an embedded Qt application. This application shall have a couple of windows which are invoked by button click. I don't know if I understood the concept of using qmainwindow in the right way:

Do I create one `QMainWindow` class and each other window that should be displayed is a widget placed as central widget or is any new window I call a new `QMainWindow`?

I do not use qmainwindow's tool, menu or status bar just the dock widgets which surround the central widget, like a header on top and a button bar at the bottom or a widget to the reight like a keyboard. Since the header's label stays the same (only the title and the icon changes) and the bottom bar always holds some button (which should call another central widget or return to the previous one), changing the central widget should be sufficient right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Qt Documentation: Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html)

Remember you can nest layouts, so you probbaly want a QVBoxLayout, and the second entry in that layout will be a QHBoxLayout.